# Recurring.php and RecurringData.php

Tags: magento2, setup-script, recurring, setup-upgrade, versioning

Can anybody explain the purpose of this two files in Setup folder? When should I use it? 
I know, that it fires every time when I run setup:upgrade

But I want to know at least one example of usage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found this from online sources:

The recurring scripts are executed after any module setup. If a module needs to do something everytime other modules are installed it can do it via the recurring script.

In **Magento2** you can check in `Magento\Indexer\Setup\Recurring` class
where `Magento_Indexer` module checks for new defined indexers and adds them to indexer_state table.

Comment: subquestion: does it run even if no new module is setup ? I gues not

Comment: @medmek recurring scripts and data will run always when we run the upgrade command 
 : bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> Please check RecurringData.php worked for me.

```
<?php
        namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;


        class RecurringData implements InstallDataInterface
        {

            protected $_indexerFactory;
            public $indexerIds = array(
                    'catalog_category_product',
                    'catalog_product_category',
                    'catalog_product_price',
                    'catalog_product_attribute',
                    'cataloginventory_stock',
                    'catalogrule_product',
                    'catalogsearch_fulltext',
                );


            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory
            ) {
                $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
            }

            public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
            {
                $this->reindexAll();
            }

            public function reindexAll() {
                foreach ($this->indexerIds as $indexerId) {
                    $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create();
                    $indexer->load($indexerId);
                    $indexer->reindexAll();
                }
            }
    }
```