# How to write Recurring scripts patch in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

How to create a data patch which execute every setup upgrade command.
We can run it after deleting from **patch_list** table but is there any other way ?

Comment: please check link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219648/recurring-php-and-recurringdata-php

Comment: @HiteshBalpande according to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html
Recurring scripts existed before Magento 2.3

Comment: did you find latest Recurring scripting patch code. can you please answer to your question.

Comment: @HiteshBalpande No I didn't. I used old method for now.